# How to set Allure reports with Maven

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, allure

I have selenium setup with testng using maven. I want to configure allure reporting functionality. I looked up Allure website and set it up.While running it gives is blank reports.

Comment: try to open the report in Firefox

Comment: not working, i think i am having the wrong configuration with my pom.xml. I used the same exact pom.xml from allure website.

Comment: make sure you have target/allure-results folder with xml files after running your tests

Comment: Any idea what should be ideal entries to add to get allure report in pom.xml?

Comment: never mind it worked.. thanks guys

Comment: could you please post a right answer?

Comment: Allure report generates JSON file or XML. For JSON use 
<plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
            </plugin>
for XML use
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
     </plugin>

Comment: New adaptors (v2.0) generates json files instead of xml

Comment: ok. I was using xml. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Configure your POM with below plugins and add Allure2 dependencies in POM and then run the tests.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-allure-environment</id>
                    <phase>pre-site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/allure-results</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>environment.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>${allure.version}</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```